# How to validate all the files in a multiple file uploader using ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

In my application i have a file uploader which accept multiple files in a single fileupload control i need to validate the extensions of all the files in that file uploader in such a way that it should accept only doc and docx.Suppose if i select 5 files in a file uploader all the files should be of -b.doc,-b.docx,-b.DOC and -b.DOCX, if there are any other extensions other than these four i should show an error message and clear the files which are in that particular file uploader how can i do this below is my file uploader code.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filDoc" runat="server" multiple="multiple"/>
```

i tried the below code the problem is it is showing alert instead it should show error message after displaying the error message it should clear the files in file uploader but it is showing two files

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filDoc" runat="server" multiple="multiple" onchange ="checkFileExtension(this);"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkFileExtension(elem) {
            var filePath = elem.value;
            if (filePath.indexOf('.') == -1)
                return false;

            var validExtensions = new Array();
            var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            //Add valid extentions in this array
            validExtensions[0] = 'doc';
            //validExtensions[1] = 'pdf';

            for (var i = 0; i < validExtensions.length; i++) {
                if (ext == validExtensions[i])
                    return true;
            }
            alert('The file extension ' + ext.toUpperCase() + ' is not allowed!');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code looks fine and I've just modified a little bit with `onChange` event. Check out the below:

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function checkFileExtension() {
    var chkFile = document.getElementById('<%= filDoc.ClientID %>'); //Gets the control of files uploaded
    var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblMsg.ClientID%>'); //Gets the control of the label to show message

    for (var i = 0; i < chkFile.files.length; i++) { //Iterates the control using a for loop 
       var myFile = chkFile.files[i].name.substr(-7); //Gets the file extension name with an array
       var myFile2 = chkFile.files[i].name.substr(-6);

       if (myFile == "-B.docx" || myFile == "-b.docx" || myFile2 == "-B.doc" || myFile2 == "-b.doc") { //Validates the file extensions
                label.innerText = "Valid Format"; //Finally outputs the result
       }
       else {
          label.innerText = "Invalid Format";
          chkFile.value = "";
       }
    }
 }
</script>
```

**ASP.NET**:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filDoc" runat="server" onchange="javascript:return checkFileExtension();" />
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Note**: I've attached a `GIF` here - You can see now how it works.

[image: Sample Image - File Uploader Validation]

Comment: can you produce the code for doing it in better way

Comment: I've already shown a way to do it @abc and I believe, you'll find a better one. Explore a bit.

Comment: no issue but i have another file uploader which should check only for .wma and .aiff that means they contain 
123.wma or 123.WMA or 123.aiff or 123.AIFF here i only need to validate for .wma and .aiff it does not contain -b like that 
it only contains filename with extension

Comment: You can customize the above code and more specifically, just change the ID of the controls. In the if conditions of the `JavaScript`, replace the file extension names. See my updated post and go through step by step.

Comment: it is not working i have choosen 200-b.docx,201-B.docx,202.wma and 203.wma with same order it is saying validformat

Comment: These are the file extensions you wanted and are valid. What do you want exactly? Do you want it to follow any pattern?

Comment: Then these files are obviously valid and the above code works exactly you have written. Now I can't understand why you are writing it doesn't work.

Comment: the problem is take a fileuploader and select the files with these extensions 200-b.docx,201-B.docx,202.wma and 203.wma actually the result should be invalid format but if we select for three to four times in the same order it is showing valid format

Comment: Check now @abc. Finally you can get your expected result and give a try :D As a sample: **-B.docx, -b.docx, -B.doc, -b.doc** - `Valid Format`, **-B.docx, -b.docx, -B.doc, -b.doc, -B.zip** - `Invalid Format`, **-B.docx, -b.docx** - `Valid Format`, **-B.doc, -b.doc** - `Valid Format`